# Visual Studio 2022 is adding a breakpoint in one of my C# files when I debug my app, and I don't want a breakpoint there

Tags: c#, debugging

I've been experiencing an odd problem with Visual Studio 2022 with one of my projects recently.  The project is in C#, and when debugging, Visual Studio automatically adds a breakpoint at one of the lines in one of my C# files.  It's consistently the same line in the same file. That's not a line where I want a breakpoint, and I'm often debugging different code in the project.  What might cause that?  And how do I stop Visual Studio from automatically adding breakpoints when I run my app in debug mode?

Comment: Have you tried removing the breakpoint and saving the project?

Comment: If you are using git - run `git clean -fdx` (do not forget to commit and push all changes needed) and rebuild (probably restart VS). Otherwise try manually cleaning VS user-specific files and folders (.suo  and .vs ones for example),

Comment: I have this problem sometimes. I've noticed deleting all break points fixes the issue. This can be done with the hotkey `control + shift + F9`, or it can be accessed in the debug menu.